# Installing varnish on Debian 10 (Buster)

Tags: varnish

It seems that varnish 6.1.1 offered by Debian repo is marked as 'security' and fix is only available on varnish version ^6.2.1

so I looked around and landed here https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish62/install

Where I can only find packages for Debian Stretch Bionic or Xenial.

There doesn't seem to be a source package either.

Is there a reason for https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/ not to have any packages for the Debian Buster ?  Not even the 6.1 ?

What should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an ongoing project, weeklies for buster will land next week if all goes well, then 60lts and 63 will get them.

Note that the project have multiple ways for you to contact them and ask about this, stackoverflow is definitely not the best channel for such specific inquiries.

Comment: `the projects have multiple ways for you to contact` : I must be really dumb.... but still hunting for any ways to contact the project ... `support@packagecloud.io` ?  .... I must be blind sorry, but can't see it.  Is it I should register in packagecloud ? thanks.

Comment: too late to edit this previous comment.  (sorry but after 2 years that I'm hunting for a way to find out where I rally feel stupid.)

Comment: Is there any reason for the 'current' debian version to always end up last in there ? (same happened month after debian 9 was out)

Comment: Hi... Really sorry that I was upset, but it's not like I tried to find a better place, so if you know a better place, please name it. Thx

Comment: Hi, sorry, I could have been a bit clearer. The project I was talking about is Varnish Cache, it's website is https://varnish-cache.org/, and I was thinking about this page in particular: https://varnish-cache.org/support/index.html

Comment: and event with this... I still don't see where I could ask this kind of question ... dev test annonce bug commit... ok, now I see `varnish-misc` ... and now I feel dumb ;)  Thanks for your help Guillaume

Answer (score 2):

https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish64/install shows this script:

```sh
# curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/varnish64/script.deb.sh |bash
```

and then

```sh
# apt-get install varnish
```

Comment: debian buster appeared almost 6 month after it was put out as current version.  That is what I was pointing out, each time debian put live a new current release, there aren't varnish package available for ages while you could find packages for debian unstable.